# jax-rs, active mq integration

Tags: cxf, activemq-classic, cxfrs

Can anyone give me a sample source code where i can use restful jax-rs web service as an interface to message broker using active mq. The requirement is traffic comes to application through jax-rs webservice and the message is transferred to active mq which is processed asynchronously and the consumer on active mq inserts data into db. Can anyone please provide sample code, that would be great

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for the same. Could you guide me please. I have a Restful service API developed with JAX-RS and jersey. I have deployed the same in TOMCAT 7. Now I would like to implement Active Mq so that I would keep all request in a queue and process the api. How to do this and integrate with tomcat7. From this article; I would be able to integrate ActiveMq with Tomcat7. but how to call the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very fuzzy. There are multiple concerns to take into account when doing this kind of interfaces as jax-rs is a http interface (synchronous, non transcational, non persistent, non guaranteed delivery) while activemq (jms) is the other way around, asynchronous, transactional and persistent.

I suggest you take a look at [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org) which is a lightweight integration framework that works really good with ActiveMQ. It supports [JAX-RS](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs) as well. There are multiple code examples over at the Camel website and connecting rest with activemq is rather easy given you have your case fully designed.